# PHP: How to make changes to the order of key-value-pairs in arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, key

OK, so here comes my question: the following code starts off with array `$a`, then calls `messUp($a)`. The task is to insert code in the place ***where the comment in block capitals resides in the code below*** so that a call to the commented-out, third `doOutput($a)` functions produces the same result as the first call to `doOutput($a)`, without changing anything else in the code. I want to know if this is possible.

```
$a = array(111, 222, 333);

doOutput($a); // output call 1

messUp($a);

doOutput($a); // output call 2

// YOUR ANSWER MUST WORK BY INSERTING CODE HERE AND ONLY HERE

// doOutput($a); // output call 3, to be uncommented

function messUp(&$array) {
  $temp = $array[0];
  unset($array[0]);
  $array[0] = $temp;
}

function doOutput($array) {
  foreach ($array as $elementKey => $elementValue) {
    echo "Key: ", $elementKey, "\tValue:", $elementValue, "\n";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

As it stands, the code outputs the following from output calls 1 and 2:

```
Key: 0    Value:111
Key: 1    Value:222
Key: 2    Value:333

Key: 1    Value:222
Key: 2    Value:333
Key: 0    Value:111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, perhaps the answer was easy this time:

```
ksort($a);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NKN He is the author of the question :-)  But I agree, the answer isn't very clear.

Comment: Why not. I've answered my question by providing the code to accomplish what I was asking. Of course, the answer works only because we know that the keys in the original array are sorted, otherwise the task at hand would involve guess-work and so would be impossible as the question stands.